# I'm stucking with setting sqlite3 on php5.3.3 in centos 6.4

Tags: php, centos, zabbix

I'm trying to setup zabbix 2.2.3 on centos 6.4 (no internet connection). I'm forced to use only sqlite3 on setting up zabbix. So I keep finding and upload push rpm to that machine. Process keep going until I found that sqlite3 does not appear in "Check of pre-requisites" page of Zabbix's installation. So I google that found php-pdo give me a sqlite3 driver. I install it with rpm. ini and so files go to the right place. But I can't bring sqlite3 enable on php -m or php -i. Anyone has a solution for this issue :).

Answer (score 0):

Note that using Zabbix server and, consequently, Zabbix frontend with SQLite is not really supported, see [ZBX-8422](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-8422). Instead, SQLite support is meant for Zabbix proxy and works well there.